# Disable encode unicode strings in Apache Axis client

Tags: java, jsf, axis, gsoap, unicode-string

I use Apache Axis in JSF portlet to connect with gsoap2 server.

There is a problem with strings from my client. I need to send some strings in UTF-8 in cyrillic. But client transform strings in my request to ASCII like боб

gsoap server have some problems with those strings transformation.

I know this is not really good way, but when I use standalone gsoap client - I don't have this transformations and requests served fine.

So, i there any way to disable unicode string encoding in Java Apache Axis?

Comment: How is this jsf related?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use the `SOAP_C_UTFSTRING` flag for the gsoap server context setup to store UTF-8 in octet-based strings or perhaps use wide strings?